# Запрос для автоматического подставления id записи в UPDATE?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Необходимо менять статус наличия товара на "нет в наличии", если товар не обновлялся более 2-ух дней.
Есть код:

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value` = 'outofstock' WHERE `wp_postmeta`.`meta_key` = "_stock_status" AND `post_id` = 162989
```

Вот условие отбора:

```
WHERE post_modified < (NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY) AND post_type = 'product' AND post_author = 178"
```

Возможно ли автоматически подставлять id записи в UPDATE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно этот вариант вам подойдет

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value` = 'outofstock' WHERE `wp_postmeta`.`meta_key` = "_stock_status" AND `post_id` IN ( SELECT ID from wp_posts WHERE post_modified < (NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY) AND post_type = 'product' AND post_author = 178 )
```

Comment: Да, спасибо большое, это то, что нужно